# How to deconstruct an object using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

So I tried to fetch data from my API, and I used `concat` and `promise.all`, here's my code

```
public async timelinePost(user_id:string){
        const currentUser:any = await LocalAuthModel.findById(user_id)
        const userPosts = await PostModel.find({userId:user_id});
        const friendPosts = await Promise.all(
            currentUser.followings.map((friendId:any)=>{
                return PostModel.find({userId:friendId})
            })
        )
        console.log(userPosts)
        console.log(friendPosts)
        const posts = (userPosts as unknown[]).concat(friendPosts)
        return posts;
    }
```

I have to use map to find all the followings's post of current user , so I used `map`, and here's friendPosts look like.

```
[
  [
    {
      likes: [],
      _id: 60f012d6aa101557b2c3ff82,
      userId: '60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4',
    },
    {
      likes: [],
      _id: 60f012f0aa101557b2c3ff8c,
      userId: '60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4',
    }
  ]
]
```

and when I tried to combine these two  it looks like below

```
[
        {
            "likes": [],
            "_id": "60ecd2521599b86baeb89b98",
            "userId": "60ebc2404a6ed456750998b1",
        },
        {
            "likes": [],
            "_id": "60ef06eeff7b684c1e6803c5",
            "userId": "60ebc2404a6ed456750998b1",
        },
        [
            {
                "likes": [],
                "_id": "60f012d6aa101557b2c3ff82",
                "userId": "60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4",
            },
            {
                "likes": [],
                "_id": "60f012f0aa101557b2c3ff8c",
                "userId": "60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4",
            }
        ]
]
```

I wonder how to remove the [] in friendPosts because apparently that's not what it supposed to be.

Comment: Simply `friendPosts[0]` would do it in this example. But it would be better to find out _why_ there is an extra level of array nesting here, what it means, and how your code should deal with the situation of more than one (or zero!) arrays here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const users = [
        {
            "likes": [],
            "_id": "60ecd2521599b86baeb89b98",
            "userId": "60ebc2404a6ed456750998b1",
        },
        {
            "likes": [],
            "_id": "60ef06eeff7b684c1e6803c5",
            "userId": "60ebc2404a6ed456750998b1",
        },
        [
            {
                "likes": [],
                "_id": "60f012d6aa101557b2c3ff82",
                "userId": "60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4",
            },
            {
                "likes": [],
                "_id": "60f012f0aa101557b2c3ff8c",
                "userId": "60ebc2584a6ed456750998b4",
            }
        ]
]

console.log(users.flat())
```